# How do I uninstall Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uninstall

I'm currently dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 8. Ubuntu is pretty much broken, and everywhere I've looked doesn't have a solution, so I wish to uninstall it. I read that it's possible to uninstall Ubuntu by deleting its partition on Windows. I checked to see what partitions I have, and there are 7 unused partitions, and I'm not sure which one to delete.

[image: pic of partitions]

Is there any way to know which partition is Ubuntu so I don't delete the wrong one?
Can I just delete Disk 0? Disk 1 is full of files that have names (like OEM, EFI, Recovery, etc).

Comment: It might help to check thep artition situation from ubuntu as well, if it is still bootable

Comment: I can't because Ubuntu is broken.

Answer (score 2):

You can not delete Ubuntu partitions from Windows just because Win can't see Ubuntu (or any other linux) partitions. Like others already wrote, you need to boot into a Live linux (Live Ubuntu or any other), open GParted and notice an ext partition. That's where Ubuntu is. Also look for a swap partition. That's used by Ubuntu also. You can delete them both if you want Ubuntu gone.

DO NOT delete EFI partition!! It is needed by any and all operating systems (including Win). EFI partition contains the GPT partition table records/data. If you  delete that you will render all installed operating systems inoperable.

Recovery partition is made by Windows. It contains some Windows critical data backup. When Win fails to boot, Win will use backup data from Recovery partition to repair itself. Some people delete that partition (since Win rarely manage to repair anything). I recommend keeping it, it's not very big or anything in the way.

OEM partition is, obviously, made by the hardware producer. It may contain proprietary drivers or rescue software. Not absolutely necessary since you can always find that software on the internet.

Usually, the Windows partition is the active partition. Disk 0 seems like an external thumb drive (judging by size). I see no reason to keep that as active partition, unless planning to install Ubuntu from it.

Just remember that, after you delete Ubuntu, the Ubuntu's bootloader (GRUB) may still be present on your hard drive and you will have to use the Windows install disk to repair the Windows bootloader.

Comment: Disk 0 is apparently just used as a small cache and is an SSD. I may be wrong on this, but I read that partitions made by linux can be seen, but they just show up as having no name or info.

Comment: Sorry about the ssd mistake.  Win can see the space occupied by the linux partitions. Win just doesn't recognize linux partitions. It will label it as unknown format. And deleting unknown formats may result in unexpected errors. You can do it on your own risk. Or on Windows risk. Whichever seems most fair to you. If the linux partition is at the end of the disk, it might be safe to delete it from Win, but if it's an intermediate partition, deleting it (from Win) may result in disk blocks being misnumbered.

Answer (score 1):

from that pic it looks like your windows 8 partitions are all NTFS so don't delete those.

Any of the partitions that don't say a type will be unused by windows so they would be most likely to be the right ones.

The only other explanations would be having other OS'es or if you have been changing the partition type labels.

Comment: Should I just delete disk 0? That seems to be the one that is being used by linux, the ones in Disk 1 all have names (ie, Recovery, EFI, etc)

Comment: ah the labels are hiding in that view , i'm not used to that program.

disk 0 is only 14.91GB , is it a removable disk ? its probably a good idea to remove all non essential filesystems when doing this section to reduce risks.

could you do the screen shot again with the status column expanded to all its data is complete and not truncated

Comment: It's not a removable disk, but I do remember that when installing Linux I partitioned only around a fourth of my hard drive for Ubuntu, and the rest for Windows.

Comment: you definitely have two drives there , partitions are parts of a drive

Comment: alright, just looked it up for my laptop, one there is one hard drive and one SSD. the SSD is just used as a cache. So now I just have to find out which partition on disk 1 is being used for linux.

Comment: so I think I found them. There are two partitions that are not being used by windows and are just labled "primary partition"

Comment: be careful these might be efi boot partitons as warned by @ipse lute

Answer (score 1):

Boot using a ubuntu live usb and delete the partition using G Parted partition editor.It clearly shows your ubuntu os labelled.Then change the boot order woth Windows boot manager on top